# What advantage does black gain from this move?

Tags: tactics

Consider the following:

```
[FEN "r3q1k1/p2p1p1p/b1p2QpB/8/8/2r5/P4PPP/R5K1 b - - 0 1"]
```

Why is black's next move Qf8? White just follows with Bf8.

Comment: Make it a habit to suggest a better move when asking questions like this one. Your chess could profit a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good way to stop `Qg7` mate. Black has to give up their queen.

Comment: For this reason, one might argue that "resigns" is the best move for Black in the given position!

Comment: Black has to give up a queen and a rook for a bishop.  Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

Black's move is forced to stop mate at g7.  He has no other alternative. The c3 rook will also fall if the bishop is then recaptured, so the game is hopeless for Black.